# Excel vba macro to move portion of column down one row when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working brute-force macro which, when a condition is met (values in two other cells are not equal), moves the cell values of rows 9 to 243 of two particular worksheet columns downward one row at a time (starting at row 243 and working up toward row 9), and then inserts a zero value in row 9 of each of the two columns. I know there must be a much more elegant and efficient way to do this using ranges; unfortunately I have no "range" experience. I apologize in advance for my ignorance, and would be thankful for some help. I promise to do my best to learn from any examples presented. ~ Snorkel

```
Sub Downshift()
    If Worksheets("Proc").Cells(53, 4).value <> Worksheets("XIV").Cells(9, 2).value Then
        For x = 244 To 10 Step -1
            For y = 115 To 116
                Worksheets("XIV").Cells(x, y).value = Worksheets("XIV").Cells(x - 1, y).value
                Worksheets("SH").Cells(x, y).value = Worksheets("SH").Cells(x - 1, y).value
            Next y
        Next x
        Fox y = 115 to 116
            Worksheets("XIV").Cells(9, y).value = 0
            Worksheets("SH").Cells(9, y).value = 0
        Next y
        Worksheets("Proc").Cells(53, 4).value = Worksheets("XIV").Cells(9, 2).value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, in effect you are cutting and pasting? I may have not got all the details correct, but this should be along the right lines.

```
Sub Downshift()

If Worksheets("Proc").Cells(53, 4).Value <> Worksheets("XIV").Cells(9, 2).Value Then
    With Worksheets("XIV")
        .Range(.Cells(9, 115), .Cells(243, 116)).Cut .Range(.Cells(10, 115), .Cells(244, 116))
        .Range(.Cells(9, 115), .Cells(9, 116)).Value = 0
    End With
    With Worksheets("SH")
        .Range(.Cells(9, 115), .Cells(243, 116)).Cut .Range(.Cells(10, 115), .Cells(244, 116))
        .Range(.Cells(9, 115), .Cells(9, 116)).Value = 0
    End With
    Worksheets("Proc").Cells(53, 4).Value = Worksheets("XIV").Cells(9, 2).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I knew there had to b a simple, straightforward way! Thanks so much!

Comment: Oops! Just a slight modification need as your code doesn't downshift the row 9 values to row 10. Range(.Cells(9, 115), .Cells(243, 116)).Cut .Range(.Cells(10, 115), .Cells(244, 116))

Comment: Ok, amended above.